# KafkaStreams interactive queries with Spring-Kafka

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

I am writing a Spring Boot app with Spring Kafka. 
As my app is focused on Kafka Streams and I need to use interactive queries and query my state stores I am wondering: **is there any particular way to access kafka streams state stores with Spring Kafka**?

From what I've seen there is some support in Spring Cloud Stream Binder Kafka Streams for interactive queries but I cannot find anything about them in Spring Kafka. 
Am I missing something or there is no support for it in Spring-Kafka?

And if so - is there anything in particular I should have in mind while creating my own version of `org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.streams.InteractiveQueryService` ?

It seemed a little too much to include Spring Cloud Streams when all I use is only Kafka and Kafka Streams but if interactive query support provided there would be difficult to implement on my own maybe it is recommended to include it anyway? I would appreciate any advise.

Comment: AFAIK, `spring-kafka` is just for producer/consumer API, not Kafka Streams

Comment: Note: `spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams` **includes** `spring-kafka`, so there is no reason you couldn't use them together

Comment: spring-kafka supports Kafka Stream. https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.2.3.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#kafka-streams.

Comment: I know that `spring kafka` supports kafka streams in general and I am familiar with documentation. My question is specifically about state stores and interactive queries. Using `spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams` seemed like adding another layer and I would like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: It is not difficult to implement your own `InteractiveQueryService` by accessing the underlying `KafkaStreams` object if you want to avoid using Spring Cloud Stream for this. Spring Cloud Stream provides idiomatic usage of accessing the state store, but if you don't have the requirement of going to a micro services based model, then I understand that you might want to use spring-kaka directly.

Comment: @sobychacko Actually I do have requirement of going to microservices based model and with multiple instances of my service I will have state store ditributed across all of them, therefore I will have to find the one that currently has data I'm interested in. That is, from what I've seen handled in Spring Cloud Stream but not in Spring Kafka.

Comment: Yes, if are not using Spring cloud Stream, in that case, you need to programmatically access the state store and interact with it. Thats where using the binder might help you there.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you use Spring-Kafka and Kafka-Streams, 
i suggest you to define your KafkaStreams as @Bean so spring will take care of the lifecycle of the object, having something like

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfig{
  @Bean
  KafkaStreams ingestAndAggregateStream(KafkaProperties kafkaProps){
  Topology t....
  KafkaStreams stream = new KafkaStreams(t,kafkaProps.buildStreamsProperties())
  stream.start();
  return stream;
  }
}
```

Once you do that you can autowire the stream in the controller and use it to retrieve and query the LOCAL KVStore

```
@RestController
public class StreamingController {

  private final KafkaStreams ingestAndAggregateStream;
  public StreamingController(KafkaStreams ingestAndAggregateStream){
    this.ingestAndAggregateStream = ingestAndAggregateStream;
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/queryStore", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  @ResponseBody
  public Value getKVStoreValue(@RequestParam String key){
    ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<String, Value> store = ingestAndAggregateStream
        .store("KV_STORE_NAME",
            QueryableStoreTypes.<String, Value>keyValueStore());
    return store.get(key);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `@EnableKafkaStreams` on you application, then you can autowire `StreamsBuilderFactoryBean`.
You can inject `StreamsBuilderFactoryBean`, and then get the `KafkaStreams` object from it with `.getKafkaStreams()`:

```
@RestController
public class StreamingController {

  private final KafkaStreams ingestAndAggregateStream;
  public StreamingController(KafkaStreams ingestAndAggregateStream){
    this.ingestAndAggregateStream = ingestAndAggregateStream;
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/queryStore", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  @ResponseBody
  public Value getKVStoreValue(@RequestParam String key){
    ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<String, Value> store = ingestAndAggregateStream
        .store("KV_STORE_NAME",
            QueryableStoreTypes.<String, Value>keyValueStore());
    return store.get(key);
  }
}
```